# Chromecast CTA Button

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am developing a Chromecast-Required Game for Android and IOS.

On Android i have the problem i don't know how to create a call-to-action button like in the guidelines:

Site 32 of https://developers.google.com/cast/downloads/GoogleCastGameUXguidelines-v20151203.pdf

Currently I am using the standard button in the action bar with the cast api v2 (not v3 because of the gameManager)

Comment: Have you already checked the [cast API documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers) for it?

Comment: yes, nothing :/